# i-adjective + noun: is there a difference which part negate?

Tags: adjectives, negation, i-adjectives

Is the following two sentence correct? And is the translate correct too?:

それ は おそ**くない** くるま です。- That car is not slow.

それ は おそい くるま **じゃ ありません**。- That car is not slow.

Or has it somthing difference in the meaning?

Which negation is recommended to use?

Comment: "That car is not slow" isn't actually a very literal translation of either of these sentences. それはおそくないくるまです is "That is a car that isn't slow," while それはおそいくるまじゃありません is "That isn't a slow car." "That car is not slow" would be more like そのくるまはおそくありません.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For:

> それ は おそくない くるま です。

the basic sentence is

> それは くるま です
> That is a car.

But おそくない modifies くるま to give "that is a car which is not slow".

For:

> それ は おそい くるま じゃ ありません。

the basic sentence is

> それは くるま じゃありません
> That is not a car

But おそい modifies くるま to give "that is not a car which is slow".

So the main difference is that in the first sentence you are asserting that it **is** a car with some property (lack of slowness) and in the second sentence you are asserting that it **is not** a car with some property (slowness).

Which one to use would depend on what you wanted to emphasise.

Comment: I see! Thank you!

Comment: @ZeroProcess Also, in the second sentence, the thing may not even be a car. While in the first sentence it is definitely a car. For example, an airplane is not a slow car.